# How to solve Getting org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: failed to respond in Jmeter with just 50 threads ,within 10 secs of thread initiation?

Tags: jmeter

I am getting this error when running the Jmeter script with 4 API calls as part of the thread group. I have started seeing this error usually with 10 to 15 requests fired and less than 20 secs of the script being executed. This is coming randomly like some times 5% of the calls fail some times it goes upto 75 to 80%. Set the Timeout value as 100000 ms also.

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 10.157.254.115:80 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can "solve" on JMeter side.

As per [NoHttpResponseException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/current/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException.html) JavaDoc:

> Signals that the target server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response.

so you need to "solve" this on the server side, the possible reasons could be in:

1. Incorrect configuration of the server when it comes to maximum number of worker threads, consult your application server documentation, it might be the case you also need to kick off an extra instance and set up a [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) in front.
2. Lack of resources, ensure that the application server has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, network sockets, etc. If you don't have monitoring toolchain you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this
3. It might be also caused by the underlying database problem like [deadlock](https://vladmihalcea.com/database-deadlock/) so check your database slow query logs for any suspicious entries
4. And last but not the least it might be a bug in the code, re-run your test with [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) enabled and see what exactly causes slow responses or errors